# Sitefinity 4.4 upgrade to 5.1 - Forums not loading

Tags: sitefinity

So I've upgraded from Sitefinity 4.4 to 5.1 and the new built-in Forums aren't loading. Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

I've compared my configuration files and everything seems to be in order. The only item I see relating to forums in the App_Code\Sitefinity\Configuration\ForumsConfig.config file which is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<forumsConfig xmlns:config="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration" xmlns:type="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration:type" config:version="5.1.3450.0">
    <notifications newPostNotificationTemplateId="2749c96b-6fe0-4796-828c-086d4fc928dd" newThreadNotificationTemplateId="f05b4fe5-752e-4fe4-b41c-69c81b73e424" />
</forumsConfig>
```

If anyone knows where else to look, please let me know. I bet it's in the DB somewhere, but I have no idea where to start...

---

Edit: So, I've now copied my new files to the DEV server with the old configuration files from before the upgrade. When this happens, I now get the following error immediately on the page load:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity,
>   Version=4.4.2117.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563'
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

So I went in and updated any reference to 4.4.2117.0 in the configuration files to 5.1.3450.0 (except in the SystemConfig.config file). Most of these changes were modifying the XML's root node's config:version property.

Ran the site again, and still got the same error.  So I found some information about putting the following into the web.config file for each file it complains about (yep, this happened 4 times):

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.1.3450.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Model" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.1.3450.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.OpenAccess" publicKeyToken="7CE17EEAF1D59342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="2012.2.628.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.1.3450.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Now, I get the following error:

> Could not load type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Publishing.PipeFactory' from
>   assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=5.1.3450.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563'.

I've already change the system to point Telerik.Sitefinity to use the latest version, but now the site won't load at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you upgraded the site to 5.1, in addition to the regular upgrade steps here: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/upgrade

did you also complete the steps here: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/upgrading-sitefinity-4.3-and-4.4-projects

and here: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/upgrading-the-web.config-and-the-sitefinitywebapp.csproj-files

in the latter step you have to add a referece to the forums.dll, as well as some other web.config stuff that might affect the project's ability to load the resources that appear to be missing...

if you did complete all the steps let me know and I'll see what else I can come up with :)

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: another good idea is to do a diffmerge between your project and the "Empty Project" folder that is in the same folder as your project manager. this will let you see if anything is missing or different in your setup.

Comment: I've gone through these steps and I'm able to get everything to work on my local database (a backup/restore from production a few weeks ago) and localhost website. But now, when I deploy to my DEV server, I'm getting the same issue. I'm guessing the problem isn't the web files (because those were all copied from a working version on my machine), but it's an issue with the database. How do I get the DEV database to work with the upgrade?

Comment: when you deploy, are you copying the local site to remote, replacing it? or uploading the local site and letting it upgrade the dev server in place? if the latter, you need to make sure to exclude the /App_Data/Sitefinity/Configuration folder because otherwise it will think the upgrade is complete and not execute properly (check step 9 in the first link above). let me know if this isn't what you're doing.

Comment: I updated the information above after these steps. I was trying to merge my web files to the DEV server, not completely replace the database and the website on the DEV server.